# How to get max rectangle basing inside an object

Tags: matlab, max, rectangles, binary-image

I have a binary image on MATLAB. Assume that there is one object in image, and pixel values of ones and zeros represent the object and the background respectively. I want to get the rectangle with max volume that can be based inside the object. Is there any built-in function or suggestion of algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: I'd look into `regionprops` with the `'BoundingBox'` property specified.

Comment: 'BoundingBox' property returns the smallest rectangle containing the object. But I need the max rectangle which contained by the object.